# Is the following relation $R$ reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric, and/or transitive?

Tags: solution-verification, relations

I am currently studying for an exam and one of the problems I am working on is asking me about relations.

Consider the set of all students at a school. We define a relation $R$ on this set.

**Statement:** $(a,b)\in R$ if students $a$ and $b$ take exactly the same set of classes in the semester.

I need to state whether $R$ is or is not reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric, and/or transitive.

Initially, I ruled out that $R$ is not antisymmetric. After some time working through it, I am thinking that $R$ is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive. Since the students are taking the same set of classes, it is clear that $R$ would be symmetric and reflexive. However, I am unsure if transitivity can be applied to $R$. Am I on the right track? If not, can someone explain why my initial answer is incorrect?

Comment: Your answer is correct, if you consider that we're comparing the sets of classes of $a$ and $b$ then the transitivity follows from the transitivity of equality.

Comment: Notice that "take exactly the same set of classes in the semester" is an equivalence relation and so reflexive, symmetric and transitive should be true. Why is transitivity true? If I take the same classes as you and you take the same classes as him, shouldn't I be taking the same classes as him?